# ICU timezone coversion from IANA to windows ID not working in windows

Tags: c++, windows, timezone, icu, iana

So, I have been trying to convert IANA timezone to windows ID in c++. Here is my sample code.

```
#include <ucal.h>
#include <wchar.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
    
    wchar_t buffer[128];
    UErrorCode status;;
    DWORD dwResult = 0;
    DWORD iterator = 0;

    DYNAMIC_TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION dynamicTimezone = { 0 };
    DWORD i = 0;
    
    printf("\n\n\n");

    int length = 128;
    char tz_info[128] = "America/New_York";
    size_t len = strlen(tz_info) + 1;
    wchar_t text_wchar[128];
    mbstowcs_s(0, text_wchar, len, tz_info, _TRUNCATE);
    auto result = ucal_getWindowsTimeZoneID(text_wchar, -1, buffer, ARRAYSIZE(buffer), &status);
    if (U_SUCCESS(status)) {
        printf("result = %d, Windows %ls:%s <- IANA %ls\n",
            result, buffer, "None", text_wchar);
    }
    else {
        printf("FAILED");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now that above code works when I use "icu.h" header and include the system libraries icuuc.lib and icuin.lib. However, in my project, I would like to use a custom build icu (v63), but when I use the custom built `.libs` and `.dlls` the function returns a result length of 0 and there is nothing in buffer.

I did not find many resources on how to use custom built icu for timezone conversions. Is there anything else that needs to be done or added? Do we need to specify or load data files separately?

I am not sure if data files needs to be loaded separately, I think they are loaded with `icudt.lib` and `icudt.dll` file.

TIA.

Comment: Did you go through [updating the time zone data](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/datetime/timezone/#updating-the-time-zone-data) and read about [ICU's options for data loading](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu/userguide/icu_data/#flexibility-vs-installation-vs-performance)?  When you built your custom icu, how did you set `--with-data-packaging`?

Comment: Also, I believe `dynamicTimezone` is extraneous in your example.  That's for a Win32 time zone data structure anyway, loaded from the Windows data in the registry - not from the ICU time zone data.

Comment: I thought by default the data is loaded in the `icudt.dll` file? This is the command I used to build `msbuild source\allinone\allinone.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64`

Comment: When I build the icu using msbuild, is there a way to specify `--with-data-packaging=library` ? I saw that this is set only for `runConfigureICU` script.